# String tokenization in prolog

Tags: prolog, tokenize, dcg

I have the following context free grammar in a text file 'grammar.txt'

```
S ::= a S b
S ::= []
```

I'm opening this file and able to read each line in prolog.
Now i want to tokenize each line and generate a list such as

```
L=[['S','::=','a','S','b'],['S','::=','#']]  ('#' represents empty)
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the specification in a DCG. I give you the basic (untested), you'll need to refine it.

```
parse_grammar([Rule|Rules]) -->
 parse_rule(Rule),
 parse_grammar(Rules).
parse_grammar([]) --> [].

parse_rule([NT, '::=' | Body]) -->
  parse_symbol(NT),
  skip_space,
  "::=",
  skip_space,
  parse_symbols(Body),
  skip_space, !.  % the cut is required if you use findall/3 (see below)

parse_symbols([S|Rest]) -->
  parse_symbol(S),
  skip_space,
  parse_symbols(Rest).
parse_symbols([]) --> [].

parse_symbol(S) -->
  [C], {code_type(C, alpha), atom_codes(S, [C])}.

skip_space -->
  [C], {code_type(C, space)}, skip_space.
skip_space --> [].
```

This parse the whole file, using this toplevel:

```
  ...,
  read_file_to_codes('grammar.txt', Codes),
  phrase(parse_grammar(Grammar), Codes, [])).
```

You say you read the file 1 line at time: then use

```
  ...
  findall(R, (get_line(L), phrase(parse_rule(R), L, [])), Grammar).
```

HTH

Comment: i've tried using your code but it isn't working. I'm trying to refine it. Can you tell me what this part of code does...`parse_symbol(S) -->
  [C], {code_type(C, alpha), atom_codes(S, [C])}.

skip_space -->
  [C], {code_type(C, space)}, skip_space.
skip_space --> [].`

Comment: i'm executing the following way and an error message is prompting  `11 ?- parse_grammar([S ::= a S b]).
ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: parse_grammar([S 
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: ::= a S b]) .` ....is this the wrong way of querying

Comment: You must use the builtin phrase/3 for interfacing with the parser, for instance:  Codes = "S ::= a S b",
 phrase(parse_grammar(Grammar), Codes, []), writeln(Grammar). will print: [[S,::=,a,S,b]]

Comment: ya i got it. but can you pls tell me what's the use of `[C], {code_type(C, alpha), atom_codes(S, [C])}.`

Comment: Please note that if you use SWI, you can parse the file more efficiently with `phrase_from_file(Phrase, File)`.  I edited @chac's response to that end.

Comment: [C], {code_type(C, alpha), atom_codes(S, [C])} parse a symbol (of 1 char). i.e. accepts a,b,..,z or A,B,...Z. code_type/2 it's the builtin that allows character classification.